Whats the difference between it = v.erase(it) and v.erase(it)?
I was reading the cppreference documentation on vectors erase method. The documentation used the general syntax: it = v.erase(it); to remove the element it was pointing to and then increment it to the next element in the vector.
By accident I noticed that:
std::vector<int> v  = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto it = v.begin();
it = v.erase(it);
std::cout << *it << std::endl; // 2

and
std::vector<int> v  = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto it = v.begin();
v.erase(it);
std::cout << *it << std::endl; // 2

seems to work exactly the same. Is there any difference between the two? If they are the same: why is it = v.erase(it); the preferred syntax? it = v.erase(it); seems a little unnecessary if v.erase(it); does the exact same.

v.erase(it); invalidates it, so using it afterwards is undefined behavior.  Whatever behavior you saw, including the sensible behavior you saw, is all within the realm of undefined behavior.  Which is why cppreference erase says "Iterators (including the end() iterator) and references to the elements at or after the point of the erase are invalidated.".

See this answer that explains "all of the iterators at or after the iterator(s) passed to erase are invalidated.
However, erase returns a new iterator that points to the element immediately after the element(s) that were erased (or to the end if there is no such element). You can use this iterator to resume iteration."
